# Having problems sorting a Angular drop down box

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

We have an in house system and as we are not in touch with the developers anymore i have been asked to change one of the drop down boxes to be sorted alphabetically.

After a bit of head scratching i have find the line of code (using HTML & Angular):

```html
<select class="form-control max-width-40" title="Vehicle" ng-model="day.plant" ng-options="plant.displayName() for plant in ctrl.plants | filter : {isVehicle: true} " ng-change="ctrl.plantOnChange(day)" ng-disabled="!day.isEditable || ctrl.isViewMode()"></select>
```

After doing some research i thought it would be as easy as adding an order by to the line E.G. :

```html
<select class="form-control max-width-40" title="Vehicle" ng-model="day.plant" ng-options="plant.displayName() for plant in ctrl.plants | orderBy : plant.displayName | filter : {isVehicle: true} " ng-change="ctrl.plantOnChange(day)" ng-disabled="!day.isEditable || ctrl.isViewMode()"></select>
```

Also tried:

```html
<select class="form-control max-width-40" title="Vehicle" ng-model="day.plant" ng-options="plant.displayName() for plant in ctrl.plants | orderBy : 'toString()' | filter : {isVehicle: true} " ng-change="ctrl.plantOnChange(day)" ng-disabled="!day.isEditable || ctrl.isViewMode()"></select>
```

but without any luck. 
Could someone please point out where i'm going wrong with this please?
i have little knowledge in this field so would appreciate some help.

Thank You

Comment: Could you create a fiddle so that we have a better picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make a small change.

```
<select class="form-control max-width-40" title="Vehicle" ng-model="day.plant"  ng-options="plant.displayName() for plant in ctrl.plants | orderBy : 'displayName()' " ng-change="ctrl.plantOnChange(day)" ng-disabled="!day.isEditable || ctrl.isViewMode()"></select>
```